# Android examples have errors

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use a SQLite database for my app, so I went in search of some examples. The problem being, when I import the code, found [here](http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/) and [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) into eclipse. it comes up with all sorts of errors. For example, this line

```
 private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";
```

has the error

```
String cannot be resolved as type
```

So given that I have no previous experience with android development, I am most baffled by the fact that the example code, which is designed to be as simple as it can be, doesn't work at all. If someone can explain what the problem is here, or what I'm doing wrong it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does `String` resolve to a type in a standard Java project?  Make sure the project build settings include a JDK reference.

Comment: providing a stack trace or some of the code would help with diagnosing the problem

Comment: @adavis he gave all the code necessary to figure out its a build path issue since `String` can't be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> String cannot be resolved as type

This would indicate that you imported a project that expected an Android SDK version that you do not have installed.

Go to Project > Properties > Android. In the checklist of Android SDK versions, check one of them, as if I am correct, none are presently checked.

Comment: Bingo, thank you, I never would have thought about that

Comment: @ChuckFulminata: What's odd about your case is that the tools used to automatically substitute in another SDK version, whatever you had installed, to avoid this case. I'm not sure if there is something different with the tools, the projects, or your environment that caused things to go haywire for you. Regardless, I'm glad to hear that it is working for you.